# is there a shorthand for 'primary key' in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I want to do this:

```
select *
from mytable
where *short-hand-for-primary-key* = 100
```

Is there a shorthand for *short-hand-for-primary-key*?

Comment: **id** :-) isn't it?

Comment: No, there's no such thing.

Comment: What's wrong with just using the column name of your primary key?

Comment: Nothing, other than I generally know the table name but if i dont always know the primary key name.. Obviously one can look it up - but I had a hunch there was a shorthand for it.. Perhaps not though.